# How do you create a workflow in which you calculate the prevalences for topics (LDA)?

Tags: r, lda

```
lda_dtm <- cast_dtm(data = gruppierte_texte,
                    document = "id",
                    term = "lemma",   #in der Zeile stehen die Tokens
                    value = "anzahl")

Themen <- seq(5,50,5) 

for(k in Themen){
  print(paste("aktuell bei Thema:", k))
  set.seed (42) # Zufall steuern, Startpunkt einstellen, immer gleiche Ergebnisse 
  
res <- LDA(x = lda_dtm, k = k)   # es geht um die häufigsten Themen  # res steht für results

praevalenzen_mit_metadaten <- make.dt(res, 
                                      meta = corpus$meta)

praevalenzen_mit_metadaten <- as_tibble(praevalenzen_mit_metadaten) %>%
  rename_all(~sub("Topic","Topic_",.)) %>%
  gather("Topic", "praevalenz", starts_with("Topic")) %>%
  mutate(K = k) %>%
  select(K, Topic, praevalenz, artist, title, record.name, lyrics, year)

}
```

This is my script, in which I want to make a LDA for a dataframe with german songs.
I want to calculate the prevalence of themes within the texts across all models.

But I got this Error:

Error in model$theta : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Can anybody help?

Comment: Which line gives this error? `make.dt` or your long chain starting with `as_tibble`

Comment: `make.dt`  only work on the output of `stm`, not on the output of `LDA`   I am not sure what you are trying to calculate. Do you just want to know how frequently each topic is the most likely topic for a document? Or do you want something else?

Comment: Yes I want to know how frequently each topic is the most likely topic for a document. Do you know how I can calculate this for a LDA?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide your data, I will use the example data included in the `topicmodels` package. The function `topics` returns the most probable topic for each document,  so you just need to put them in a table.

```
library(topicmodels)

data("AssociatedPress", package = "topicmodels")
lda <- LDA(AssociatedPress[1:40,], control = list(alpha = 0.1), k = 3)

table(topics(lda))

 1  2  3 
15 13 12
```